# POST redirect to GET passing variable other than in the URL

Tags: php, html

Is there a thread safe way of passing variables when redirecting a POST to a GET without passing the variables in the URL?

What I'm trying to achieve is this. I have a page that contains a form that allows users to upload images. That form is sent by the browser to my server as a POST. If the image upload is successful, the page is redirected to a GET where I want to show the image that the user has just uploaded. The only safe way I can think of passing a variable between the two pages is via a GET parameter.

ImageUpload.php

```
$imageID = processImageUpload();

if($imageID){
    redirect("/ImageDisplay.php?uploadedImageID=".$imageID)
}
```

ImageDisplay.php

```
$uploadedImageID = getRequestVariable('uploadedImageID');
if($uploadedImageID != FALSE){
    //Display the image just uploaded with an 'image uploaded success!' message
}

//Display all the other images
```

Although it's not the worst thing in the world, having the variable included as a GET param is a bit ugly. It's also slightly misleading as if the user hits refresh on the redirected page the will see the 'image uploaded success!' message again, even though they haven't just uploaded an image.

Is there another way that is thread safe of passing variables from the POST page to the GET page?

Using session or cookies variables aren't safe as there could be two images uploaded at once and so there could be race conditions.

I thought I could use an redirect and then read the referrer header e.g.:

1. POST to ImageUpload.php which redirects to
2. GET ImageDisplay.php&uploadedImageID=123 which redirects to
3. GET ImageDisplay.php where I would read the referrer from the previous
   GET request.

However it seems that the referrer is always the page that held the upload form, not any if the intermediate steps.

Is there any other way of passing a variable from one request to another, other than as a GET parameter?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method I have suggested is ugly but it won't show the variables in the query string to the user.

Consider modifying your **ImageUpload.php** file as follows (untested code):

```
$imageID = processImageUpload();

if($imageID){
    <?php
        <!Doctype html>
        <html>
            <head>
                <title>Upload successful! Redirecting...</title>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    window.onload = function () {
                        document.getElementById("redirectionForm").submit();
                        return;
                    }
                </script>
            </head>
            <body>
                <div style="text-align: center; padding: 50px; font-style: italic;">
                    Image upload successful!
                    <br />
                    Please wait while you are redirected...
                </div>
                <form id="redirectionForm" action="ImageDisplay.php" method="post">
                    <input type="hidden" name="uploadedImageID" value="<?php echo $imageID; ?>" />
                </form>
            </body>
        </html>
    ?>
}
```

This will output a form on the client which in-turn will redirect the user to **ImageDisplay.php** with the relevant POST data information.

Comment: Hi Tanzeel, That's certainly slightly ugly but does do exactly what I want. 
However I can make it even better by: 
i) having the first redirect go to the GET with the variables as normal.
ii) On that GETed page, display the upload results as normal, as well as have that auto-submitted form be there but hidden.

That way if a user doesn't have Javascript enabled, they will still see the upload results as normal (with variables in the URL) and if they have JS enabled, they will be redirected to the clean URL version.

Answer (score 1):

I think that passing GET parameter is a good choice for following reason :

- Using a GET parameter will allow you to create an independent API. Suppose user uploads 10 pics and have 10 different values for a parameter, suppose, "imageName". Now the API can be independent allowing user to make calls like :

  1. ....getImage?imageName=1
  2. ....getImage?imageName=2
  3. ....getImage?imageName=3

What you may do is just rewrite the URL after the request has been completed so that the URL doesn't look ugly with **imageName** parameter.

**I suppose keeping data in session should be last resort**. Data in session makes it very difficult for the application to scale at Runtime. A server can't be shut down for maintenance before all the sessions on that server are closed. Essentially session data creates lots of troubles.

Comment: Hi Amber, agree GET are better than session vars but I added why I'm looking for something even better: "It's also slightly misleading as if the user hits refresh on the redirected page the will see the 'image uploaded success!' message again, even though they haven't just uploaded an image."

Although it's safe for the user to hit refresh, I'd prefer it to only display the 'image upload success' once.

Comment: It requires a simple check. If the refresh is on a page with Image upload success don't show the message againb. You can check the "Referer" of the page from request to verify the same.

Comment: Hi Amber, even if you hit refresh the referrer is still the original referrer. It doesn't change to be the page that you're on.

Comment: @Danack I think following article might help you : http://www.tedpavlic.com/post_detect_refresh_with_javascript.php

Answer (score -1):

You could set custom headers like:

```
header('X-UploadedImageID: 123');
```

You can access the headers by [headers_list()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.headers-list.php):

```
headers_list();
```

A `var_dump()` of the this would look something like:

```
array(2) {
  [0] =>
  string(35) "X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.19"
  [1] =>
  string(22) "X-UploadedImageID: 123"
}
```

So to get the 123 you would just need to do something like:

```
$headers = headers_list();
echo str_replace('X-UploadedImageID: ', '', $headers[1]);
```

Which will give you: `123`

Make sure you set these headers before you output any data and before you call your header location redirect.

**Change your ImageUpload.php to:**

```
$imageID = processImageUpload();

if($imageID){
    header('X-UploadedImageID: ' . $imageID);
    redirect("/ImageDisplay.php");
}
```

**Change your ImageDisplay.php to:**

```
$headers = headers_list();
$uploadedImageID = str_replace('X-UploadedImageID: ', '', $headers[1]);

if($uploadedImageID != FALSE){
    //Display the image just uploaded with an 'image uploaded success!' message
}
```

Comment: +1 I really like your suggestion. It is clean and you have correctly prefixed custom headers with an `X-`.

Comment: Hi Steven, can you clarify how that would work? I understand how I pass the 'X-UploadedImageID' to the browser when I do the redirect but how does that get passed from the browser to the server again for the GET request?

Comment: The browser won't forward any custom headers you set, so subsequent requests won't see the header.

Comment: Hi Steve, I saw you edited your answer. I still don't see how the header 'X-UploadedImageID' is passed back from the browser to the server.